# Deserialize separate key-value pair from Json string

Tags: spring, jackson

I have a class

```
Entity implements org.joda.beans.Bean {
    String name;
    double weight;
    ....
}
```

I have an endpoint like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "CREATE", method = POST)
public void createEntity(@RequestBody Entity entity) {
    logic.createEntity(entity);
}
```

Frontend sends a Json string to this endpoint:

```
{"name": "Bob", "weight":"99.7"}
```

Now I want to have another endpoint to update the entity.
It accepts json strings where only part of the attributes are set:

```
{"weight":"99.8"}
```

Its signature could be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "UPDATE", method = POST)
public void updateCompany(@RequestBody Map<String, String> update1) {
    Map<String, Object> update2 = deserialize(Entity.class,update1);
    logic.updateEntity(update2);
}
```

The question is, how to implement the method `deserialize` which takes pair of Strings ["weight","99.8"] and converts it to the pair String-Object: ["weight", Double.valueOf("99.8")] because it knows, that the type of weight is double as declared in the class `Entity`. Such conversion was done already while preparation of arguments for the method `createEntity()`, now I want to extract it as a separate method call.

Answer (score -1):

1. Deserialize to `Map<String,String>`
2. Iterate over each entry
3. Crete String->Double pair
4. Put to `Map<String,Double>`

Comment: "Crete String->Double pair"
Double is only as example, I need a general case, where the string-value should be converted not to Double, but to the type of the property named with string-key.

Comment: I dont see that in your example